# Question on first countable spaces

Tags: general-topology

I am struggling with this old qualifying exam problem and would greatly appreciate any help.

Suppose that $X$ is a ﬁrst countable, Hausdorﬀ space and $A$ is a subset of $X$ which
intersects each compact subset of $X$ in a set closed in $X$. Prove that $A$ is closed.

Comment: The question is very interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x$ be a limit point of $A$. Since $X$ is first countable, there is a local base $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ at $x$ such that $B_n\supseteq B_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ choose $x_n\in A\cap B_n$. Let $$K=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{x\}\;.$$ Show that $K$ is compact, and conclude ... what?

Comment: Indeed, Hausdorffness is not necessary here. The sequence together with all its limits is compact, and if $A$ intersects this union in a closed set, then it contains every limit of the sequence.

Comment: @Stefan: The sequence together with all of its limit points need not be compact if there are infinitely many limit points.

Comment: Ah, you are right! Didn't thing about that :-)